# Is it possible to embed a command line statement in a Hyperlink?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, network-drive, net-use

Here's what I'm trying to make happen:
User gets automatic email-reply with a hyperlink inside. The hyperlink contains a net use command to map a network drive. A confirmation should not be necessary.

Really hope that this is possible, as a batch file on the server automatically has outlook asking for confirmation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: It would be a serious security breach if this were possible. A hacker could send an email with such link and hell would break loose.

Comment: This is a great way to distribute viruses and hack systems. That is why it isn't possible.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are trying to automate setting up this mapped network drive for multiple users.  How many users?  What other types of connections or shared spaces do you have that are in common?  For instance, do you have a commonly shared local folder such as, OneDrive, Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, Amazon Cloud?  There are much better, safer, and secure ways of automating other PCs than email even without Active Directory or Group Policy servers.

Comment: Actually it's really just about personal folders on a file server for which users have to request access. We were just looking for a quick simple way via Mail, as the creation script sends a confirmation email.
AD and group policies are to remain untouched as this is handled company-wide. The server is just a local thing and it should stay that way.

Comment: You can't have a policy for your local group of workstations to run a script upon login to map a drive? That's what we do. You'd think you could filter LDAP by location, or some other way to uniquely identify your users on your site.

Comment: Even without modifying AD or GP, there could be an easy way to command those PCs to map this drive.  Obviously, all your PCs have some shared folder with read-right access.  I'm suggesting an intelligent script that "listens" and "executes" commands after certifying these commands were unmodified and only originating from you.  Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround here may be making a link to a shared batch file on the network.

So, hyperlink is

```
<a href="file://///remoteserver/remotedirectory/adddrive.bat"> Click me to add the drive! </a>
```

The batch would be

```
net use (drive info)
```

The only caveat here is that the batch file will download and ask to run.